# How to reset the password of the lock screen programmatically on Android SDK 26 or higher

Tags: android, securityexception, device-admin, device-policy-manager

In my application I want to change the password of the lock screen programmatically. So I wrote this method to reset the password:

```
@TargetApi(26)
private void changePasswordWithToken() {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] token = secureRandom.generateSeed(32);
    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    if (devicePolicyManager != null) {
        devicePolicyManager.setResetPasswordToken(compName, token);
        devicePolicyManager.resetPasswordWithToken(compName, "1234", token, 0);
    }
}
```

When I call the method I get this error on my device running Android 9 SDK 27

```
va.lang.SecurityException: Admin ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxxx.MyAdmin} does not own the profile
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
        at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setResetPasswordToken(IDevicePolicyManager.java:9995)
        at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.setResetPasswordToken(DevicePolicyManager.java:3091)
        at com.ssaurel.lockdevice.MainActivity.changePasswordWithToken(MainActivity.java:136)
        at com.xx.xx.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:93)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
...
```

Before I call this method, I' getting the device admin permissions with this method

```
private void provisionDeviceAdmin() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, compName);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    "Additional text explaining why we need this permission");
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);
}
```

My policies looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
        <reset-password />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this solution worked out:

At first, define admin device permissions

**policies.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <reset-password/>
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>`

Then create a class that extend `DeviceAdminReceiver`

```
public class MyAdmin extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin : enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Device Admin : disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/**
 * Generates a {@link ComponentName} that is used throughout the app.
 * @return a {@link ComponentName}
 */
public static ComponentName getComponentName(Context context) {
    return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), MyAdmin.class);
}
```

}

Get admin device permission with this function in your `MainActivity`

```
private void provisionDeviceAdmin() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, MyAdmin.getComponentName(this));
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    "Additional text explaining why we need this permission");
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);
}
```

Then provision a working profile for your app in the `MainActivity`

```
private void provisionManagedProfile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);

    // Use a different intent extra below M to configure the admin component.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        //noinspection deprecation
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME,
                        MyAdmin.getComponentName(this));
    } else {
        final ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this,
                                                          MyAdmin.class.getName());
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_COMPONENT_NAME,
                        component);
    }

    if (intent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);
        this.finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device provisioning is not enabled. Stopping.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

After that set the application package to the working profile

```
 private void setAppEnabled(String packageName, boolean enabled) {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager =
            (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    try {
        int packageFlags;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24){
            //noinspection deprecation
            packageFlags = PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;
        }else{
            packageFlags = PackageManager.MATCH_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES;
        }
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                                                                            packageFlags);
        // Here, we check the ApplicationInfo of the target app, and see if the flags have
        // ApplicationInfo.FLAG_INSTALLED turned on using bitwise operation.
        if (0 == (applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_INSTALLED)) {
            // If the app is not installed in this profile, we can enable it by
            // DPM.enableSystemApp
            if (enabled) {
                devicePolicyManager.enableSystemApp(MyAdmin.getComponentName(this), packageName);
            } else {
                // But we cannot disable the app since it is already disabled
                Log.e("TAG", "Cannot disable this app: " + packageName);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            // If the app is already installed, we can enable or disable it by
            // DPM.setApplicationHidden
            devicePolicyManager.setApplicationHidden(
                    MyAdmin.getComponentName(this), packageName, !enabled);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "The app cannot be found: " + packageName, e);
    }
}
```

Create a method to generate random password tokens

```
private byte[] generateRandomPasswordToken() {
    try {
        return SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG").generateSeed(32);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally implement this method to reset the lock screen password with token

```
 @TargetApi(26)
private void changePasswordWithToken() {
    byte[] token = generateRandomPasswordToken();
    DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(null, null);
    if (devicePolicyManager != null) {
        devicePolicyManager.setResetPasswordToken(MyAdmin.getComponentName(this), token);
        devicePolicyManager.resetPasswordWithToken(MyAdmin.getComponentName(this), "1234", token, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the documentation, it clearly states there that:

> Called by device or profile owner to force set a new device unlock
>   password or a managed profile challenge on current user. This takes
>   effect immediately.

From your code it does not look as if you are a "device or profile owner"; please don't mix that up with "device admin" which your apps seems to be (or is trying to get not sure if it is really successful from your code).